# converting pandas dataframe to xarray dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-xarray

```
   Unnamed: 0       index    datetime  ...   cVI     Reg       average_temp
0           0  2000-01-01  2000-01-01  ...   NaN  Central           -5.883996
1           1  2000-01-02  2000-01-02  ...   NaN  Central           -6.715087
2           2  2000-01-03  2000-01-03  ...   NaN  Central           -6.074254
3           3  2000-01-04  2000-01-04  ...   NaN  Central           -4.222387
4           4  2000-01-05  2000-01-05  ...   NaN  Central           -0.994825
```

I want to convert the dataframe above to an xarray dataset, with `datetime` as the index. I do this:

```
ds = xr.Dataset.from_dataframe(df)
```

but I am not able to get the `datetime` column as index. How do I do that?

Comment: not really clear to me what is not covered by Michael's answer as it provides an xarray dataset with `datetime` as index that can be used to, well index the dataset. Maybe you can share the expected result or elaborate?

Comment: Is the problem solved by the below answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xarray will treat the index in a dataframe as the dimensions of the resulting dataset. A MultiIndex will be unstacked such that each level will form a new orthogonal dimension in the result.

To convert your data to xarray, first set the datetime as index in pandas, with `df.set_index('datetime')`.

```py
ds = df.set_index('datetime').to_xarray()
```

Alternatively, you could promote it afterwards, with `ds.set_coords('datetime')` and then swap the indexing dimension with [`ds.swap_dims`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.swap_dims.html):

```py
ds = df.to_xarray()
ds.set_coords('datetime').swap_dims({'index': 'datetime'})
```

I'd recommend the first option but the second also works if you already have your data as a Dataset and want to swap the index.

Comment: thanks @Michael, however, even after doing this, the datetime column type stays as object. Is there a way to get its type to be datetime?

Comment: you can convert the column in the dataframe first with [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), e.g. df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])`

Answer (score 1):

First use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) on the desired column:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df = df.set_index('datetime')

#             cVI      Reg  average_temp
# datetime                              
# 2000-01-01  NaN  Central     -5.883996
# 2000-01-02  NaN  Central     -6.715087
# 2000-01-03  NaN  Central     -6.074254
# 2000-01-04  NaN  Central     -4.222387
# 2000-01-05  NaN  Central     -0.994825
```

Then your [`xr.Dataset.from_dataframe`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.from_dataframe.html) code will work as expected:

```
ds = xr.Dataset.from_dataframe(df)

# <xarray.Dataset>
# Dimensions:       (datetime: 5)
# Coordinates:
#   * datetime      (datetime) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 ... 2000-01-05
# Data variables:
#     cVI           (datetime) float64 nan nan nan nan nan
#     Reg           (datetime) object 'Central' 'Central' ... 'Central' 'Central'
#     average_temp  (datetime) float64 -5.884 -6.715 -6.074 -4.222 -0.9948
```

Or as Michael said, convert it from the pandas side using [`df.to_xarray`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xarray.html):

```
ds = df.to_xarray()

# <xarray.Dataset>
# Dimensions:       (datetime: 5)
# Coordinates:
#   * datetime      (datetime) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 ... 2000-01-05
# Data variables:
#     cVI           (datetime) float64 nan nan nan nan nan
#     Reg           (datetime) object 'Central' 'Central' ... 'Central' 'Central'
#     average_temp  (datetime) float64 -5.884 -6.715 -6.074 -4.222 -0.9948
```